# jquery conflict when adding jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, conflict

I am trying to use the `jquery.scrollableFixedHeaderTable.js` extension to make my table header fixed while you scroll through a table .

but when I try to add `jquery.min.js` for `tooltip` plugin, and for some reason `scrollbar` is not working and the `tooltip` is working well
here is a source [link](http://www.dropbox.com/s/8vo12xh4iyeayaf/min_js_conflict.zip)

or http://jsfiddle.net/jassyr/8vwSt/

Comment: Nobody is going to download your zip I guess. Try to create a simple JSfiddle instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are overwriting your jQuery-library after you add the jQuery-plugin:

```
<!-- here you declared it for the first time --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- here you declared your plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.scrollableFixedHeaderTable.js"></script>
<!-- however, here you do overwrite your jQuery-declaration -->     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://itsmeara.com/jquery/atooltip/js/jquery.min.js">  </script>
```

Remove the second jQuery-declaration and it will work fine.

Comment: I've deleted the seconde jquery declaration but still not working!

Comment: Do you still get the same error as before or is the functionality itself not working? Also, in which file are you testing? (the first or the second?) Could you also give me an updated version of your ZIP-file, as the fiddle (updated in your post) seems to be working fine?

Comment: as you can see the scrollbar with fixed header is working but the tool tip near the "hello world" is not working!
i need both of them to work

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that in your question. Place your function `$('td.normalTip').aToolTip()` inside `$(document).ready(function() {` and it will work fine. Events can only be assigned to elements if they exist at that time. Working code: [http://jsfiddle.net/4YSR4/]

Comment: please can you paste the full function the jfiddle link is not working

did you add the jquery.min.js?

Comment: I'm not used to post links here. This should work: [http://jsfiddle.net/4YSR4/](http://jsfiddle.net/4YSR4/)

Comment: but when try to add the jquery.min.js (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)
it makes conflict with jquery-scrollablefixedheadertable.js
you can take a look at the external ressources

Comment: If you add that as `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the fiddle, it will indeed give problems there. However, that's why the menu at the left (frameworks & extensions) is for. Just apply the changes in your own offline version and you should be okay.

Comment: I've added <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to my source code offline and it is not working!
It makes conflict with  jquery-scrollablefixedheadertable.js
in the console i got this error: 
$(...).scrollableFixedHeaderTable is not a function

Comment: Why are you adding jQuery another time? Please view my original answer about how that overwrites your events. If you are absolutely positive that you haven't declared a jQuery-library under your jQuery-plugin (only above!), please send me another link of a zipped version of your code(as the fiddle is working fine). Otherwise, this will be my last answer.